# requireFailure for vertical/horizontal pans with hammer.js on meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, hammer.js

I'm trying to implement a "cards" kind of interface like [this example](https://cdn.rawgit.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/master/tests/manual/nested.html) with **hammer.js** on **Meteor** (the [chriswessels:hammer-js](https://github.com/chriswessels/meteor-hammer) package).

So far, I've got the horizontal pans working but I can't get the vertical pans to work along properly. Somehow the requireFailure won't work for me and **the vertical pans only work after a horizontal pan trigger** (I'm trying to have both directions work independently).

I have a hammertoucharea like so:

```
{{#HammerTouchArea configureCallback=configureHammer gestureMap=templateGestures}}
    [...]
{{/HammerTouchArea}}
```

And this is my config code:

```
configureHammer: function () {
    return function (hammer, t) {
        var vertical = new Hammer.Pan({
            event: 'panv',
            direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL
        });
        var horizontal = new Hammer.Pan({
            event: 'panh',
            direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL
        });
        vertical.requireFailure(horizontal);

        hammer.add([vertical, horizontal]);

        return hammer;
    }
},
```

And my gestures look like this:

```
templateGestures: {
    'panleft .sliderH': function (e, t) {
        //slide right
    },
    'panright .sliderH': function (e, t) {
        //slide left
    },
    'panup .sliderH': function (e, t) {
        //slide down
    },
    'pandown .sliderH': function (e, t) {
        //slide up
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!